An asymptotic for a sum involving gamma functions
I have a rather scary sum
$$S(n) = \sum _{k=0} ^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma^A\left( k+an+1 \right)\Gamma^B\left( k+bn+\frac12 \right)}{\Gamma^{A-1}\left( k+1 \right)\Gamma^{B-1}\left( k+\frac12 \right)}\frac{1}{\Gamma^2\left( k+ cn+\frac12 \right)}$$
where all of the parameters are positive integers and $c>\frac{aA+bB}{2} +\frac34$ to insure convergence. I want to find the behavior of $S(n)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
I carelessly tried to replace the summation operation with a definite integral and because the summands $s_k$ attain their maximum at a value of $k$ proportional to $n \gg 1$, we can apply Stirling's formula and Laplace's method. This gives the following leading behavior:
$$\log S(n) \sim (aA+bB-2c)\cdot n\log n + \mathcal{O}(n)$$
which matches numerical evaluations decently but overall not quite right, as if you can't just replace sums with integrals. So my question is, how should I go about finding this asymptotic? Maybe there's a heuristic argument? An analog of Laplace's method for sums?
Also, $S(n)$ turns out to be an example of a Meijer G-function of the form
$$G_{A+B,A+B}^{A+B,~1}\left(-1\left|\begin{matrix} \{1\}_{A-1},\{1/2\}_{B-1},\{cn+1/2\}_2\\
\{an+1\}_{A},\{bn+1/2\}_B\end{matrix}\right.\right)$$
but I'm afraid I don't know enough about G-functions to use that knowledge.

where does this sum even come from?

@Sahaj, I was trying to construct a certain Diophantine approximation and it appeared in a hypergeometric form $${}{A+B} F{A+B-1} ({an+1}A, {bn+1/2}B; {1}{A-2}, {1/2}{B-1}, {cn+1/2}_2;1)$$

It seems that if you push the expansion of the Gamma function a bit further (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Log-gamma_function ), you might get a more precise expansion of the term of the series. You can then use the Euler-MacLaurin formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula to approximate the series by an integral, and use a more precise version of the Laplace method on that integral. With enough hard work, you should be able to get as precise an asymptotic as you desire.
